# Images on Bootstrap site in unordered list won't display in Firefox but will in Safari & Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an unordered list of thumbnails that display in Safari 5.1.7 & Chrome 33.0.1750.152 but not Firefox 27. My site is www.zrrdigitalmedia.com . I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap 2. Here's the HTML

```
<h1 name="ads-section">ADS</h1>
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <article class="row-fluid">
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/expedia.jpg" data-lightbox="image-6" title="Expedia Ad for Filter" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="Expedia Ad for Filter" src="img/ads/expediaThumb.jpg">
                <h3>Expedia Ad for Filter</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop.</p>
            </a>
       </li>
       <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/geek.jpg" data-lightbox="image-7" title="GeekWire Ad for Filter" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="GeekWire Ad for Filter" src="img/ads/geekThumb.jpg">
                <h3>GeekWire Ad for Filter</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop & Maya.</p>
           </a>
       </li>
       <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/inrix.jpg" data-lightbox="image-8" title="Inrix Ad for Filter" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="Inrix Ad for Filter" src="img/ads/inrixThumb.jpg">
                <h3>Inrix Ad for Filter</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </article>
    <article class="row-fluid">
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/micro.jpg" data-lightbox="image-9" title="Microsoft Ad for Filter" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="Microsoft Ad for Filter" src="img/ads/microThumb.jpg">
                <h3>Microsoft Ad for Filter</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/msn.jpg" data-lightbox="image-10" title="MSN Ad for Filter" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="MSN Ad for Filter" src="img/ads/msnThumb.jpg">
                <h3>MSN Ad for Filter</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/natgeo.jpg" data-lightbox="image-11" title="National Geographic Ad for Filter" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="National Geographic Ad for Filter" src="img/ads/natgeoThumb.jpg">
                <h3>National Geographic Ad for Filter</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </article>
    <article class="row-fluid">
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/aa1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-12" title="Amber-Allen Ad" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="Amber-Allen Ad" src="img/ads/aa1Thumb.jpg">
                <h3>Amber-Allen Ad</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/aa2.jpg" data-lightbox="image-13" title="Amber-Allen Ad" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="Amber-Allen Ad" src="img/ads/aa2Thumb.jpg">
                <h3>Amber-Allen Ad</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="img/ads/dsf.jpg" data-lightbox="image-14" title="DSF Ad" class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="DSF Ad" src="img/ads/dsfThumb.jpg">
                <h3>DSF Ad</h3>
                <p>Designed in Photoshop.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </article>
</ul>
```

Why aren't the thumbnails & images showing up in Firefox 27? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem: disable adblockplus in Firefox.